# ldap always having permission denied when using "set_lg_dir" in DB_CONFIG

Tags: permissions, openldap

I set the ldap transaction log files to a directory that is different from /var/lib/ldap:

I create the directory /var/logDB/ldap
chown -Rf ldap:ldap /var/logDB/ldap
chmod 777 /var/logDB/ldap

Then in the file DB_CONFIG , I put this line :
set_lg_dir /var/logDB/ldap

I launch the slapd process and then 
I get always an error of permission denied ..

Did you have some ideas how to solve it ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Having just solved this issue for myself it turns out that SELinux was preventing the slapd process (OpenLDAP) from writing to the separate folder for transaction logs. Try turning off SELinux (setenforce 0) and see if that does the job for you. If it does you may want to look into adding an appropriate rule for SELinux that will allow the ldap service user and/or slapd process to access and write to your new transaction log folder.